# plot3d for readGDAL?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I would like to prepare 3D graph in R! using raster data.
I heard about command plot3d in raster package.
Unfortunately I have data in GeoTiff format, so it is impossible to read it directly through raster package (instead of it, to load this file, I am using readGDAL command).

Is there any opportunity to prepare 3D graph using such data?
How I can retrieve coordinates? I know how to get values of raster using as.matrix command, but because it is in GeoTiff format, I am unable to use xmin or xmax.

Comment: There is no plot3d function in the raster package. Do you mean plot3d in the rgl package? GeoTIFF is the best general format (IMO) for raster data so I wonder why you see that as a problem. Can you expand on what kind of plot you want? A surface plot?

Comment: @mdsumner There used to be a `raster::plot3D` function, but because of `rasterVis` appeared on the scene, was removed... From the changelog of raster:`--- 8-July-2011, version 1.8-41
removed gplot and plot3D functions. These are now in the rasterVis package`

Answer (score 1):

I do not see why you cannot read a geotiff with `raster`, but at any rate the `SpatialGridDataFrame` (package sp) provided by `readGDAL` (package rgdal) can be passed directly to `raster()`.

Here's an example with a GeoTIFF from the rgdal package. Note that the rasterVis function is in a separate package and is called `plot3D` (not plot3d which is in the rgl package):

```
library(rgdal)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster(system.file("pictures/cea.tif", package = "rgdal")[1])
plot3D(r)
```

[image: dumb default 3D plot]

The rasterVis package handles all the scaling and colours and provides a nice default.

If you want to delve further into the supporting packages, here's a simple example.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgl)

## read the file with raster 

r <- raster(system.file("external/test.ag", package="sp")[1])

## just use simple persp plot
persp(r)

## convert to sp's SpatialGridDataFrame (or use readGDAL directly)
## (for very large rasters this could be prohibitive in terms of memory)
sgdf <- as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame")

## convert to R's image() format, a list with x,y vector and z matrix

x <- as.image.SpatialGridDataFrame(sgdf)

## plot with rgl, ugly but see ?surface3d for colour options etc.
surface3d(x$x, x$y, x$z)
```

[image: easy persp plot]